# How to pass object with parameters via construct

Tags: php, class, constructor

I have a class that relies on several other classes being present. Therefore, I pass these other classes through my construct function and this all works fine. However, when I pass a class that requires a parameter for its own construct function, I get a error saying 'Missing argument 1 for mysql::__construct()...'. What is the best method for passing objects through a class with required parameters?

**If you see any potential flaws in this design, please let me know. I am fairly new to Object Orientation and resultantly am still learning.**

An example of what I currently have and is not working:

```
class mysql{
    function __construct($memcache){
        // Construct the object 
    }
}
class company{
    function __construct($databases,$connections,$mysql,$facebook){
        // Construct the object

        // Make the MySQL class available to all the methods
        $this->mysql = $mysql;
    }
}

// Initialize the objects (Company, MySQL, Memcache and Facebook)
$memcache = new memcache;
$facebook = new Facebook($facebook_config);
$mysql = new mysql($memcache);
$company = new company($_DATABASES,$_CONNECTIONS,$mysql,$facebook);
```

**SOLVED UDPATE**

*The code above is in fact correct, the problem was because I was calling `__construct()` at the end of one of my methods and I had forgotten to pass the $memcache parameter*

Comment: Your code seems ok, when did you get the error?

Comment: I thought so too! I just got the error. It occurs when I try to call a method from the mysql object via the company class. I will double check my code to make sure I havent missed anything but I am definitely passing the parameter where I initiate the class.

Comment: please give the code which gave the error.

Comment: I sincerely apologise, I have managed to find the error. I was calling __construct() at the end of one of my methods and I had completely forgetten to add the $memcache parameter. Really sorry to waste your time, thank you anyway.

Comment: You should add an & in front of the given object instance. This creates a reference to the instance instead of copying it to the method. You have to add the & in the headline of the method: function __construct($databases, $connections, &$mysql, &$facebook) {...};

Comment: Yes, I am aware of references but have never really understood the point with them. Will this reduce the resource usage of the script? What are the benefits of using references?

Comment: @BenCarey Reference works as a link to another variable or object. We still only have one variable/object, but we may have two or more names for it. Example, if we do `$a = 5; $b = &$a;` then $a is really the only variable we have, $b is only a link to $a and if we change $a then $b is also changed. But also, since $b is a link to $a and $a is the only real value, if we change $b then we also change $a.